# JQuery Tabs: Tab getting redirected to first tab

Tags: jquery

My Code:

```
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 0 );
         $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "disable", 1 );
         $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "disable", 2 );
         $("#tab3").text("");
         $("#tab1").attr("href", "makerList");
         $("#tab1").text(roleName+" Work List");
         if(mode=='add'){
             $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "enable", 1 );
             $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
             $("#tab2").attr("href", "makerAddUser");
             $("#tab2").text("Add Client");
             $("#tab2").click();


         }
```

When I am clicking on an event in first page it is focusing on the second tab for some seconds but again getting redirected to first page.

I want to get the second tab get focussed .

Can any one please help?

Comment: I think the problem happens at somewhere else.

Comment: @konghou : Can u please mention where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `event.preventDefault()` isn't being fired on your tab click, so your element's `href` property is being followed by your browser. I'm not sure how the jQuery Tabs plugin works, but I imagine this should be handled for you anyway, however a simple fix would be to add this in yourself:

```
$('[id^="tab"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This targets any element with an ID beginning with "tab" and calls `preventDefault()` on the event for you.

The problem may simply be that you're not calling `enable` on tab 2, however, and thus the plugin isn't handling that tab's click for you:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "enable", 2 );
```

Comment: I am doing this 
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "enable", 1 );
to enable my second tab as code to enable my first tab is $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "enable", 0 )